# What is ${p: ... } in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a Groovy scripts that I need to convert to another language but I can't seem to find what this code means:

```
${p:component/lib_logger}
```

or this

```
def String text = "${p:SOME_TEXT_OR_VAR}
```

I know `${...}` but the `p:` inside it, I don't know what it does.

Comment: Is that in groovy code? Or is it perhaps some other framework's lookup syntax (such as log4j)?

Comment: I think it is from other frameworks. Not sure if it is Serena.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"${p:SOME_TEXT_OR_VAR}"
```

if it's plain groovy then `p` is just a [label](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_labeled_statements) that actually ignored

so, statement above is equal to

```
"${SOME_TEXT_OR_VAR}"
```

however in some frameworks the label could be used on purpose.

for example in spock framework `given: when: then:` have a special meaning.

if so - you have to clarify your question